# jQuery $.ajax function doesn't get data from $(...).validate function

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I've faced the following trouble while trying to combine jQuery validation (plugin) and sending data to server using ajax.

If I'm using this jQuery method for only posting data to server on its own, everything is OK.

```
function doAjaxPost() {
    // get the form values
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var pswd = $('#pswd').val();

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "${pageContext. request. contextPath}/loginUser.htm",
    data: "name=" + name + "&pswd=" + pswd,

    success: function(response){    
        // we have the response
        if(response.status == "OK") {
            $('#info').html("User has been added to the list successfully.<br>"+
                                "The User Details are as follows : <br> Name : "+ 
                                response.result.name + " <br> Password: " + response.result.pswd);
            $('#name').val('');
            $('#pswd').val(''); 
        } else {
            $('#info').html("Sorry, there is something wrong with the data provided")
        }
    },
    error: function(e){
        alert('Error: ' + e);
    }
    });

}// end of doAjaxPost
```

But when I'm trying to validate user's input by using jquery.validate.min.js, the response from server shows me that everything is OK, **but the values of name and password are undefinded** I suspect that my method doAjaxPost() fails to extract data from form after jquery.validator. 
Here is my validation function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#loginform").validate({

            submitHandler: function(form) {
                doAjaxPost();
            },

            rules:{
                name:{
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 4,
                    maxlength: 16,
                },
                pswd:{
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 6,
                    maxlength: 16,
                }, 

           },
           messages:{
                name:{
                    required: "Login - is a mandatory field",
                    minlength: "Name should contain minimum {0} symbols",
                    maxlength: "Maximum symbols - {0}",
                },
                pswd:{
                    required: "Password - is a mandatory field",
                    minlength: "Password should contain minimum {0} symbols",
                    maxlength: "Password should contain maximum {0} symbols",
                },

           },

        });

    });
```

So my question is how to extract data from validated form and pass it to doAjaxPost function?

As I think these variables get nothing from form

```
var name = $('#name').val();
var pswd = $('#pswd').val();
```

Maybe I should use a selector like $('#loginform #name') ? I tried it, it doesn't work. Please, help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote OP:

> "So my question is how to extract data from validated form and pass it
>   to doAjaxPost function?"

[Use jQuery `.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) and put your `ajax` inside the plugin's `submitHandler`.

[As per the documentation for the Validate plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions), the `submitHandler` callback function is:

> "Callback for handling the actual submit when the form is valid. Gets
>   the form as the only argument. Replaces the default submit. **The right
>   place to submit a form via Ajax** after it validated."

Try this code, assuming your `ajax` function is correct:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        // your rules & options,
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            //var name = $('#name').val(); // use serialize
            //var pswd = $('#pswd').val(); // use serialize
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "${pageContext. request. contextPath}/loginUser.htm",
                //data: "name=" + name + "&pswd=" + pswd,  // use serialize
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                success: function (response) {
                    // we have the response
                    if (response.status == "OK") {
                        $('#info').html("User has been added to the list successfully.<br>" +
                            "The User Details are as follows : <br> Name : " + response.result.name + " <br> Password: " + response.result.pswd);
                        $('#name').val('');
                        $('#pswd').val('');
                    } else {
                        $('#info').html("Sorry, there is something wrong with the data provided")
                    }
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    alert('Error: ' + e);
                }
            });
            return false; // blocks redirect after submission via ajax
        }
    });

});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/Cdvqw/**

**EDIT**:  OP already had his external `ajax` function called from within the plugin's `submitHandler`.

Comment: You're absolutely correct about form serialization. 
I've added this variable 
var queryString = $('#loginform').formSerialize();
and used it as my data and everything worked great. 

I think, serializing data has sence. 
Thanks for your help.